# Trying filter query depending on a method of a related model

Tags: django, django-queryset

```
class Course(models.Model):

   def is_active(self):
      return self.enroll_set.count()>0

class CourseEvent(models.Model):

   course = models.ForeignKey(Course)
```

I want to find all `Events` that only point to active courses.
something like:

```
events = CourseEvent.objects.filter(course.is_active=True)
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate

You make an annotation, it'll be filterable as a field.

It may look like this:

```
CourseEvent.objects.annotate(is_active=Count('course__enroll')).exclude(is_active=0)
```

Comment: Definately a viable option.

Comment: I got this exception: Cannot resolve keyword 'enroll_set' into field. Choices are:

Comment: or give me the choices cause the answer should be in the end of the error message

Answer (score 2):

Your `is_active()` method makes no sense.

`is_active` would imply a boolean of some sorts not 62. So there's something you can correct right off the bat. Normally, I would set a `is_active` flag on the `Course` model (thusly removing the method `is_active` altogether) and toggle that making the ORM call really straight forward:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

events = CourseEvents.objects.filter(course__active=True)
```

Comment: I think i knows this, but as long as it's not a database field, django can't use this.

Comment: well if its active or not it depends,thats why i used a function.its not possible to query against a method return?

Comment: query is made on database, your database is not aware of your python code. So no.

Comment: No, but this would be most straight forward, if you have requirements that toggle a Courses active state then that should be a method that looks like this `def set_active(self): #do some stuff self.active = False/True`

Comment: If you don't want to handle this field or have redundant data in your base, you can also take a look to my answer.

Comment: This answer should have better performances, offer a clearer/shorter queryset calls, but you'll have to maintain the boolean and remove it from admin and other interfaces to ensure it's never wrong/user defined. Both have their adventages. For the queryset calls, you can use a custom manager: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/